# How can i plot data too far apart with MatPlotLib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics

I'm developing a simple statistics calculator, and the last step is to plot the numbers given by the user.

Everything goes fine when the numbers are close apart, as shown below with the numbers [-2, -2, 0, 1, 3, 5]: [Plot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByVYJ.png)

However, when there'are numbers too far apar, the graph breaks because of the big amount of ticks:
[Plot 2 (broken)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlLUx.png)

The code is here:

```
def plot(l = np.array(\[\]), m = float, M = float):
plt.style.use('classic')
plt.title(f'NUMBERS PLOT')
plt.ylabel('NUMBERS DENSITY')
plt.xlabel('GIVEN NUMBERS')

m = np.min(l)    #Smallest given number
M = np.max(l)    #Biggest given number

bins = np.arange(m, M+2) - 0.5     #-0.5 for aligning the bars with the ticks
freq_num = Counter(l)    #Counting the occurrence of every number
most_freq = (freq_num.most_common(1)\[0\]\[1\])   #Taking the occurrence of the most dense number
plt.hist(l, bins = bins)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, most_freq+2, 1.0))
plt.xticks(np.arange(m, M+2))
plt.xlim(\[m-1, M+2\])

return plt.show()
```

How can i, for example, exclude the zero-density numbers, for example the numbers between 20 and 60, from the x-axis?
Is there another way to avoid this result?

Comment: Try it with [sns](https://pypi.org/project/seaborn) ? The aesthetics tend to be leaps and bounds better than the raw low level matplotlib results. https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html

Comment: Good idea, gonna try here

Answer (score 1):

I think that a good option would be to apply the matplotlib [broken axis](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html) feature.

As an example, I have plotted a bimodal distribution whose peaks are far apart from each other. This example should be pretty close to your data. The broken axis allows to get a better visualization of this plot.

Here is the code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(42)

N = 1000
mu = 400
sigma = 5

mu2 = 10
sigma2 = 20

dens_1 = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, N)
dens_2 = np.random.normal(mu2, sigma2, N)
dens = np.concatenate([dens_1, dens_2])

plt.hist(dens, bins=100)
plt.show()

f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, facecolor='w')

ax1.hist(dens, bins=100)
ax2.hist(dens, bins=100)

ax1.set_xlim(-100, 150)
ax2.set_xlim(350, 450)

ax1.spines.right.set_visible(False)
ax2.spines.left.set_visible(False)
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()
ax1.tick_params(labeltop=False)
ax2.xaxis.tick_bottom()

d = .01
kwargs = dict(transform=ax1.transAxes, color='k', clip_on=False)
ax1.plot((1-d, 1+d), (-d,+d), **kwargs)
ax1.plot((1-d, 1+d),(1-d, 1+d), **kwargs)

kwargs.update(transform=ax2.transAxes)
ax2.plot((-d, d), (1-d, 1+d), **kwargs)
ax2.plot((-d, d), (-d, +d), **kwargs)

plt.show()
```

Here is the plot without broken axis:
[image]

and here with broken axis:
[image]